# Escaping double-quotes in regex, in JSON, read in to Python

Tags: python, json, regex

I've got a JSON file that contains string keys, with regex-strings as values:

```
{
    "GitHub": "[g|G][i|I][t|T][h|H][u|U][b|B]['|\"][\s]?[:|=]?[\s]?['|\"][0-9a-zA-Z]{35,40}['|\"]"
}
```

The file is then read in Python:

```
with open(args.rules, "r") as ruleFile:
    rules = json.loads(ruleFile.read())
...
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to get the regex to parse correctly. It seems to keep getting hung up on how I'm escaping the double-quotes within the regex. As the code is currently written, the interpreted regex removes the backslash that I'm using to escape each double-quote; I believe the backslash is escaping the double-quote in the JSON (it is only intended to escape the double-quote for the regex itself), which causes the code to fail when reading the file.

I've tried adding an additional backslash, or two, before the double-quotes within the regex string, however, the interpreted regex fails to read if there are two backslashes, and if I have three, then it reads successfully but keeps two backslashes.

Given the desired final regex string, how should the regex be updated to satisfy both JSON syntax and Python syntax simultaneously?

Comment: You do not need to use literal `'` and `"` in a regex, you may use `\u0022` and `\u0027`, replace `['|\"]` with `[\u0022\u0027]`

Comment: I don't think your regex is what you expect to begin with: `GiT|ub"|'mriDyPKFoVKH7WbvQM3qrjH1LvtYuDYuB6Q'`

Comment: If you add an ignore-case flag, then your regex can be `github['"][\s]?[:=]?[\s]?['"][0-9a-z]{35,40}['"]`, which is a little better: `github"= 'i50phsj4vk5p5hphbat9k63ug2njca1f918zzha"`, though the first quote (before = or :) seems strange

Answer (score 0):

Turning comments into an answer:

First off, I don't think your regex is what you expect to begin with, it would match: `GiT|ub"|'mriDyPKFoVKH7WbvQM3qrjH1LvtYuDYuB6Q'`
You should remove the or (`|`) within character classes (`[]`) as it is interpreted as a literal vertical bar.

If you add an ignore-case flag, then your regex can be `github['"][\s]?[:=]?[\s]?['"][0-9a-z]{35,40}['"]`, which is a little better: (example `github"= 'i50phsj4vk5p5hphbat9k63ug2njca1f918zzha"`, though the first quote after "github" (before = or :) seems strange.

In general, you can just start with what you want in python and then reverse it.

```
$ python
>>> import json, re
>>> desired = r'''github['"][\s]?[:=]?[\s]?['"][0-9a-z]{35,40}['"]'''
>>> example = "giThuB' ='0123456789012345678901234567890123456789'"

>>> print desired
github['"][\s]?[:=]?[\s]?['"][0-9a-z]{35,40}['"]

>>> print json.dumps({"Github": desired})
{"Github": "github['\"][\\s]?[:=]?[\\s]?['\"][0-9a-z]{35,40}['\"]"}

>>> bool(re.match(desired, example, flags=re.I))
True
```

Comment: I appreciate the simplified regex - what I've got works, but I prefer the cleaner approach :)

Comment: Not to nitpick but it works while being objectively wrong, in the case of the vertical bars (its fine to not want to ignore case with a flag).  You would want one of `[aA]` or `(a|A)`, but the syntax mixup means you match `||||||||| 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789|`